# Необходимо прикрепить вложение в письмо с длинным русским названием(с пробелами) python (библиотека email)

Tags: python, email, header

использую стандартное прикрепление файла к существующему письму(old_msg):

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    if maintype == 'text':
        msg_n = MIMEText(file.read().decode(), _subtype=subtype)
    elif maintype == 'image':
        msg_n = MIMEImage(file.read())
    elif maintype == 'audio':
        msg_n = MIMEAudio(file.read(), _subtype = subtype)
    elif maintype == 'message':
        msg_n = MIMEMessage(email.message_from_binary_file(file, policy = policy_pack.default), _subtype = subtype)
    elif maintype == 'application':
        msg_n = MIMEApplication(file.read(), _subtype = subtype)
    else:
        msg_n = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
        msg_n.set_payload(file.read(), 'UTF-8')
        encoders.encode_base64(msg_n)
    #далее прикрепляю заголовок(fn - имя файла):
    try:
        msg_n.replace_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename=fn)
    except:
        msg_n.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename=fn)
    try:
        msg_n.replace_header('Content-Type', ctype, filename=fn)
    except:
        msg_n.add_header('Content-Type',ctype ,filename=fn)
old_msg.attach(msg_n)
```

В итоге - файл прикреплен,а название не отображается: как будто файл без названия. Примером файла может выступать: "2017.06.25 Матан вопросы на экзам МСБиС.pdf".

Comment: related: [Email an attachment with non-ascii filename with python email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34668240/4279)

Comment: такие вещи лучше в вопрос помещать (чтобы форматирование нормальное было и можно было соответствующий код, который  к ошибке приводит привести).

Comment: Ошибка была устранена,но имя файла так и не поменялось.

Comment: я не понимаю что такое *"не поменялось"*. Какой конкретно код, какое сообщение генерирует (байты) и (если знаете), что вы хотели чтобы вместо этого генерировалось бы (желаемый результат).

Comment: код и переформулированный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780840/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC

Answer (score 1):

Если передать `filename` параметр в `add_attachment()` метод, то используется [rfc 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231) для имени файла в Content-Disposition заголовке автоматически:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

login, password = ... # for smtp provider such as smtp.yandex.ru

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'прикреплен файл с длиннным русским именем'
msg['From'] = login
msg['To'] = [login]

filename = ('файл с длиннным длиннным именем … '
            'прикрепить вложение в письмо с длинным русским названием'
            '(с пробелами) python (библиотека email).txt')
msg.set_content(f'смотри прикреплённый файл: {filename!r}')
msg.add_attachment(MIMEText('some text'), filename=filename)
```

Чтобы послать [это письмо](https://ideone.com/DHBAJo):

```
import ssl
from smtplib import SMTP

with SMTP(smtp_provider, timeout=10) as s:
    s.set_debuglevel(1)
    s.starttls(context=ssl.create_default_context())
    s.login(login, password)
    s.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: Данный способ также не помогает(имя файла остается неизменным). Особенность заключается в том,что я добавляю вложение к письму,в котором уже есть вложение какое-нибудь. Если к чистому письму добавляю,то все хорошо. Попробуйте добавить к файлу с вложением добавить...

Comment: @Valli  код работает как есть. Если "не помогает" значит нужно обновить вопрос и привести минимальный, но полный код, который к ошибке ведёт. Полезно явно привести bytes(msg) и лог обмена с smtp сервером.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь.
Обновлю.

Comment: @Valli чтобы убедиться что код работает, достаточно на [ссылку в ответе](https://ideone.com/DHBAJo) нажать и посмотреть на значение Content-Disposition заголовка (ожидаемое значение для rfc 2231).