# Python3 отправка e-mail с аттачем

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtplib

Хочу отправлять e-mail с приаттаченным CSV-файлом. На текущий момент скрипт выглядит так:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- Coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)
server.starttls()
server.login('my_login', 'my_password')

msg = "YOUR MESSAGE!"
server.sendmail("my@email.com", "from@email.ru", msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Пока без аттача, просто потестить сам факт отправки через внешний SMTP. Вопрос в следующем - когда запускаю скрипт в консоли, ничего не происходит. Никаких ошибок, ничего. И приглашение к вводу тоже не появляется. Ну.. то есть, скрипт делает вид, что идёт какая-то долгая тяжёлая работа. Прерываю по Ctrl+C. Письмо, соответственно, не приходит. Вопрос - что в этот момент происходит, где и как мне отловить ошибку?

Comment: чтобы узнать где висит, добавьте в вопрос полный traceback. Но и так ясно что код нерабочий. Начните с [рабочего кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/780831/23044)

Comment: @jfs скопировал Ваш код, подставив свои данные. ```smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: timed out```

Comment: если не понимаете сообщение об ошибке, то задайте отдельный вопрос с минимальным точным примером кода и полным traceback. В заголовке можно написать "timed out при отправке e-mail". Упомяните вашу операционную систему, настройки firewall, размер файла, результат `mtr smtp.yandex.ru` команды (или аналога).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     Замените 465-й порт на 587. .....
```